# Arduino Mega + SIM808 GSM + GPS Module + Program Switch ON without pressing Push Button?

Tags: arduino-mega, gsm, gps

I am new to IOT and tried out integration and a small test code with an Arduino Mega + SIM808 + GSM + GPS Module. It works fine with the SIM808 Library.

My requirement is to put it in an enclosure, but when the power restarts, for some reason we have to manually start the SIM 808 + GPS + GSM Module. Can we control it from code? Can we do a software trigger from Arduino code?

Maybe if we have some pins to connect and trigger the power on. Kindly provide inputs/suggestion for [this module](http://www.ebay.in/itm/222142520400?euid=007afe9cc2264537b4beecab12b7dd90&bu=44483664891&cp=1&sojTags=bu=bu).

If you are aware of some module that can be started through code kindly suggest.

Here's [one reference](http://www.geeetech.com/wiki/index.php/Arduino_GPRS_Shield) I found for a different module with Software Trigger.

Comment: I tried connecting D9 to 5 V and Damn it works !! ,, I don't know where didi you get that information from but it works giving 5V for D9 on sim808 evb 3.2 for 3 - 4 seconds will make it power on .

Answer (score 6):

There is a simple way of power the module without pressing the button. There is pin call D9 at the bottom right corner of the module. Just power the pin by Arduino digital pin or 5v pin around 3, 4 seconds. Then it will power the whole module. No need to press the press switch. Make sure you connect power(9V-12V) to the board and provide 5V and GND to the sim808 module. below figure shows the pin D9

[image]
[image]

Comment: This is great solution, vote up! Anyway please how did you get to this information? As I bought this board on Aliexpress I have no datasheet.

Comment: About the 5V, if the board is powered by DC044 then V_IN is not needed. Note: blue arrow on the image is pointing to the VMCU which controls the high level of TTL UART.

Comment: Google probably answered my "D9" question: https://www.elecrow.com/wiki/index.php?title=SIM808_GPRS/GSM%2BGPS_Shield_v1.1

Answer (score 0):

I can't get a great view of the board, but if you are pressing the button just below "GSM" and "Made" then I would suggest soldering some leads onto the button and connecting them to a digital output and Gnd on the Arduino.  (You might need resistors and stuff)  Then when you wanted to press the button you could pulse the line high.

Comment: Thanks ! will try the same and add relay ..and control using arduino !